# Is there any way to create treetable or treegrid in jquery dynamically where we will get data to create table from java

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, treetable

I have used static table html and used treetable plugin for that to display as treetable

```
$("#example-basic").treetable({
    expandable: true,
    // handle auto load on expand
    onNodeExpand: function () {
        var node = this;
        // update and add children as needed via ajax
        /*$("tr[data-tt-id='"+node.id+"']").after(
              '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>'
          );*/

        // remove data-tt-branch
        if (node.children.length == 0) {
            node.row.removeData("ttBranch");
            node.row.removeAttr("data-tt-branch");
            node.row.removeClass("expanded")
        }
    }
});
```

but I need to load data, even headers and roots dynamically. I didnt find anything which could create whole treetable dynamic. Can anybody help?

Comment: mmm, are you loading the elements from  ajax - could this be of use?
https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable-ajax-example

Comment: Thanks Richard, I tried that already but it says no project found to import.

Comment: Mmm, not too sure but would this be of use?
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html